# numpy min() between two vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, min, intersection

Any idea how to do intersection between two vectors with numpy. F.e.:

```
  np.random.randint(0,10,3)
  array([5, 6, 7])

  np.random.randint(0,10,3)
  array([6, 6, 3])

  [5,6,3]
```

i.e. select the minimum numbers.

Answer (score 3):

use [`numpy.minimum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html)

```
>>> np.minimum(x1,x2)
array([5, 6, 3])
```

Comment: ha, thanks ...  there is min() and minimum() which differ.